# Differential Equation derivative question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I was given this example in class:

$$\frac{dy}{dt}+\frac{y}{2}=\frac{1}{2}e^\frac{t}{3}$$

Finding $$\mu=e^\frac{t}{2}$$
After multiplying the whole equation we get:

$$\frac{dy}{dt}\cdot{e^\frac{t}{2}}+\frac{y}{2}\cdot{e^\frac{t}{2}}=\frac{1}{2}e^\frac{t}{3}\cdot{e^\frac{t}{2}}$$

However, after applying some algebra she does the following:

> $$e^\frac{t}{2}\cdot{\frac{dy}{dt}}\longrightarrow{}\frac{d}{dt}(e^\frac{t}{2}\cdot{y})$$

How does that work and when is it valid?

Thanks!

Comment: $\frac{dy}{dt}\cdot{e^\frac{t}{2}}+\frac{y}{2}\cdot{e^\frac{t}{2}}=\frac{d}{dt}(e^{\frac{t}{2}}\cdot y)$ by the law for differentiating a product

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @Snaw You should put that as an actual answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{dy}{dt}\cdot{e^\frac{t}{2}}+\frac{y}{2}\cdot{e^\frac{t}{2}}=\frac{d}{dt}(e^{\frac{t}{2}}\cdot y)$ by the law for differentiating a product.